# Does LWC @wire works with custom classes?

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I'm trying to use @wire with a method that returns a list of my custom wrapper class. The list is returned, but the items have no fields. When I'm using @wire with List of SObject, everything is fine.

Comment: Can you add code snippet? also are the fields in your wrapper class annotated with @AuraEnabled?

Comment: That's it! I forgot about @AuraEnabled on the fields. Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you declare a Apex wrapper class to be used in Aura or LWC, you have annotate each and every field with `@AuraEnabled` else they won't be visible in the JS or Markup of lwc or aura.